# Adding a user with disabled password and login

Tags: solaris

How do I add a user similar to this in Solaris (disable password, login and no home page) for service account.

```
adduser --system --ingroup group-name --disabled-password --disabled-login -no-create-home user-name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"adduser" is typically a Linux thing, but if you look at the other Shadow utils -- passwd, useradd, usermod -- they should be similar enough. Shadow (what's in Linux ...) was based on SVR1, which is what I had access to when I started writing it in 1987. "useradd" needs the "-m" option to handle the home directory, so don't supply that. And "passwd -l" locks the password by inserting an invalid character in the password field.

What you want to avoid is "chage" since that's something I made up. Even if it is a handy something.